# fixture self not found in pytest

Tags: python

I was going through the post in the below link:
[how to assign Class Instance to a variable and use that in other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811299/how-to-assign-class-instance-to-a-variable-and-use-that-in-other-class)

I am using the same code and the main code and TestInventoryCreation() test class works fine.
However when I add the TestInventoryAddstock() class that is when I get "fixture self not found" error.

My test class below:

```
class TestInventoryAddStock():inventory = None

@classmethod
def setup_class(cls):
        cls.inventory = MobileInventory({'iPhone Model X': 100, 'Xiaomi Model Y': 1000, 'Nokia Model Z':25})

def test_add_new_stock_as_dict(self):
        self.inventory.add_stock({'iPhone Model X': 50, 'Xiaomi Model Y': 2000, 'Nokia Model A': 10})
        assert self.inventory.balance_inventory == {'iPhone Model X': 150, 'Xiaomi Model Y': 3000, 'Nokia Model Z': 25, 'Nokia Model A': 10}


def test_add_new_stock_as_list(self):
        with pytest.raises(TypeError) :
            MobileInventory.add_stock(['iPhone Model X', 'Xiaomi Model Y', 'Nokia Model Z'])


def test_add_new_stock_with_numeric_keys(self):
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
            MobileInventory.add_stock({1:'iPhone Model A', 2:'Xiaomi Model B', 3:'Nokia Model C'})


def test_add_new_stock_with_nonnumeric_values(self):
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
            MobileInventory.add_stock({'iPhone Model A':'50', 'Xiaomi Model B': '2000', 'Nokia ModelC':'25'})


def test_add_new_stock_with_float_values(self):
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
            MobileInventory.add_stock({'iPhone Model A':50.5, 'Xiaomi Model B':2000.3, 'Nokia Model C':25})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to assign Class Instance to a variable and use that in other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811299/how-to-assign-class-instance-to-a-variable-and-use-that-in-other-class)

Comment: Hi John, I used the same code for TestInventoryAddstock suggested in the link but it threw the error I posted---fixture self not found

Comment: Are you tried with the same indentation as the original question? In your code, the class name and their methods are in the same indentation, not like the original.

Comment: They are in same indentation because inventory = None was declared after the class statement in same line.

Comment: However I tried with original indentation which was giving error "unexpected indent before def", so I put the inventory in different line and put indentation on each def methods but same error